# Filtering Enabled Collectors

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

The Prometheus *node exporter* does not have a simple way to disable all default metrics without passing 20 flags to the process. In the [documentation](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter/blob/master/README.md) it looks like there might be an easier way to fetch only the relevant metrics:

> Filtering enabled collectors
>
> ...
>
> For advanced use the node_exporter can be passed an optional list of collectors to filter metrics. The collect[] parameter may be used multiple times. In Prometheus configuration you can use this syntax under the scrape config.
>
> ```
> params:
>   collect[]:
>     - foo
>     - bar
> ```
>
> This can be useful for having different Prometheus servers collect specific metrics from nodes.

My assumption is you put the *params* directly under your [scrape_config](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#%3Cscrape_config%3E) because there's a matching *params* field. However, what exactly is supposed to go under *collect[]*? The examples *foo* and *bar* couldn't be any less descriptive. Is it the command-line argument (e.g., "--collector.cpu"), the collector name (e.g., "cpu"), the collector metric name (e.g., "node_cpu"), the actual metric (e.g., "node_cpu_seconds_total"), or something else?

Answer (score 5):

There is another solution that is generic and can work with all exporters. [relabel_map_config](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#%3Cmetric_relabel_configs%3E) is a configuration option that can be set inside the prometheus config file. As specified in the documentation:

> One use for this is to blacklist time series that are too expensive to
>   ingest.

Thus you can drop or keep metrics that match a regex. For instance, to only store the cpu metrics collected by the node exporter, you can use the following inside the `prometheus.yml` file:

```
scrape_configs:
 - job_name: node
   static_configs:
    - targets:
       - localhost:9100
   metric_relabel_configs:
    - source_labels: [__name__]
      regex: node_cpu_.*
      action: keep
```

Comment: That feature looks more useful.

Answer (score 1):

From testing the *node collector* the *collect[]* parameter must be the collector name. E.g., the name from `--collector.cpu` is `cpu`.

If you specify an invalid collector such as `foo`, you'll receive the following HTTP "400 Bad Request" message:

```
Couldn't create missing collector: foo
```

Answer (score 1):

As [All Workers Are Essential](https://stackoverflow.com/users/369450/all-workers-are-essential) said, the parameter expected inside the `collect[]` parameter is the **name** of the collector.

Complementing the answer, below you can find a working example of the node exporter configuration, filtering only the `cpu`, `meminfo` and `filesystem` collectors:

```
scrape_configs:
  # The job name is added as a label `job=<job_name>` to any timeseries scraped from this config.
  - job_name: 'prometheus'

    # metrics_path defaults to '/metrics'
    # scheme defaults to 'http'.

    static_configs:
    - targets: ['localhost:9090']

  # Node exporter
  - job_name: 'node_exporter'

    static_configs:
    - targets: ['localhost:9100']
    params:
      collect[]:
        - cpu
        - meminfo
        - filesystem
```

Keep in mind that the *old* collected metrics can still be accessed, but once restarted the `prometheus` service, only the filtered metrics (`cpu`, `meminfo` and `filesystem`) will be available.