# Prometheus Filtering enabled collectors

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

There is already a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53325478/filtering-enabled-collectors) regarding this. But it's not answered properly. I'm trying to understand how to use the Filtering enabled collectors in [this link](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter)

```
params:
    collect[]:
      - foo
      - bar
```

I tried

```
 - params:
                [ collect[]: ['diskstats', 'filefd', 'filesystem', 'loadavg', 'meminfo', 'netdev', 'netstat', 'stat', 'time', 'uname', 'vmstat'] ]
```

or

```
 - params:
                [ collect: ['diskstats', 'filefd', 'filesystem', 'loadavg', 'meminfo', 'netdev', 'netstat', 'stat', 'time', 'uname', 'vmstat'] ]
```

or

```
 - params:
                -collect: ['diskstats', 'filefd', 'filesystem', 'loadavg', 'meminfo', 'netdev', 'netstat', 'stat', 'time', 'uname', 'vmstat']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the the `yaml` to the Prometheus configuration under [scrape_config](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#scrape_config) like below sample:

```
scrape_configs:
- job_name: prometheus

  params:
   collect[]:
      - diskstats
      - filefd
      - filesystem
      - loadavg
      - meminfo
      - netdev
      - netstat
      - stat
      - time
      - uname
      - vmstat 

  file_sd_configs:
    - files:

  static_configs:
  - targets: ['localhost:9090', 'localhost:9191']
    labels:
      my:   label
      your: label

  relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [job, __meta_dns_name]
    regex:         (.*)some-[regex]
    target_label:  job
    replacement:   foo-${1}
    # action defaults to 'replace'
  - source_labels: [abc]
    target_label:  cde
  - replacement:   static
    target_label:  abc
  - regex:
    replacement:   static
    target_label:  abc
```

References:

- [codebase link](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/master/config/config.go#L352)
- [documentation link](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#scrape_config)